# Alternatives to XMLSerializer for very large data

Tags: c#, serialization, xmlserializer

Right now I am trying to save a large amount in memory data to my hard drive.  It currently trying to save one table with 400,000 records using XMLSerializer.  This works correctly, but the xml file has a size of over 1 gig.  All my classes implement [Serializable()]. My data is in a concurrentqueue, which I cast to List<> before I serialize.

My Question is:  Is there a better, quicker serializer that will create smaller files?  Smaller files are the most important thing I want.

EDIT:  The file does not need to be human readable.  The goal is to be able to save hundreds of thousands of records to the disk with the smallest footprint and fastest speed.  I'm looking into Binary Serialization, but am having issues with getting "system of memory" errors.  I am trying to see if there is a way to write directly to my disk without loading all my data into memory first.  Memory-Mapped Files may be an option.

I also have the option to use sql server 2008 for storage.  I was planning on using this as a secondary storage unit if the application had access to the database and store the file on the computer if it does not.

```
        var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<pPeople>));
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\...\Desktop\TestLogFile.xml", FileMode.Create);
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        xml.Serialize(tw, peoplePeople.ToList<pPeople>());
        tw.Close();
        fs.Close();

        //Deserialize
        FileStream openFS = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\...\Desktop\TestLogFile.xml", FileMode.Open);
        var savedPeople = (List<pPeople>)xml.Deserialize(openFS);
        peoplePeople = (ConcurrentQueue<pPeople>)savedPeople.Cast<ConcurrentQueue<pPeople>>();
        openFS.Close();
```

Comment: Have you looked at any compression techniques?

Comment: `JSON` would produce a smaller file. And either format could be made much smaller with compression. Does the serialization need to be human readable?

Comment: Probably nosql database would be a better choice in this case. You could also try JSON and http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/.

Answer (score 1):

if you want a small, fast to load file, don't use a serializer, and definitely don't use xml. Implement methods on your classes that save & load only the essential data to a binary stream.

Answer (score -3):

I would use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) instead of XML. .NET produce smaller files and it will be parsed faster than XML. However, if you are going to use XSLT to transform the XML to anything else I recommend sticking with XML. Here are some examples:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small"
//  ]
//}
```

As you can see it is less verbose than XML. Then you can use a javascript minimizer to make it even smaller.